# pop item from AMQ queue upon connection using stomp.py

Tags: python, queue, stomp

Currently when connecting to a queue using `stomp.Connection(host_and_port).connect(creden)` with a listener all messages are taken from the queue. Is there way to only take a message at a given position on the queue, or at least the oldest message, leaving the rest of the messages on the queue, upon connection?